# Min and max values validation using jquery issue

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am trying to do something similar to this question: [min max price range validation not working with jquery.validate.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37355054/min-max-price-range-validation-not-working-with-jquery-validate-js) . More specifically this one I am looking at: https://jsfiddle.net/rajnikpatel/4hnxhmrs/ . I tried to do this in my ASP.NET Project, but it does not validate `minYear` and `maxYear` as expected, it looks like it just ignores it and submits data anyway. When min value is higher than max value, I expected it to show an error message like the example in jsfiddle.

Here is my code for **Vehicles.cshtml**

```
@model List<GuildCars.UI.Models.CarViewModel>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Admin";
}

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <h2>Admin</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        @Html.ActionLink("Add a new Vehicle", "Add", "Admin", null)
    </div>
</div>

<style>
    .column {
        float: left;
    }

    .one {
        width: 25.00%;
    }

    .two {
        width: 25.00%;
    }

    .three {
        width: 25.00%;
    }

    .four {
        width: 25.00%
    }

    .row:after {
        content: "";
        display: table;
        clear: both;
    }
</style>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <h2>Search</h2>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <form id="searchForm" class="form-inline">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="make">Make</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="make" name="make">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="model">Model</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="model" name="model">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="year">Year</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="year" name="year">
            </div>

            <label for="minYear">Min Year</label>
            <select class="form-control form-control-all" id="minYear" name="minYear" data-name="Year Range Min" title="Min year is required" aria-required="true">
            </select>

            <label for="maxYear">Max Year</label>
            <select class="form-control form-control-all" id="maxYear" name="maxYear" data-name="Year Range Max" title="Max year is required" aria-required="true">
            </select>

            <div>
                <label for="amount">Price range:</label>
                <input type="text" id="rangePrice" name="rangePrice" style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold; width:25%" readonly="readonly" /><br />
                <input type="text" id="minPrice" hidden />
                <input type="text" id="maxPrice" hidden />
                <div id="sliderRange" style="width:250px; "></div><br />
            </div>

            <button id="btnSearch" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>

            </form>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div id="searchResults" class="col-xs-12">

    </div>
</div>

@section scripts
{
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            priceRange();
            minYear();
            maxYear(); 

            var $min = $('#minYear'),
                $max = $('#maxYear');
            console.log($min);
            console.log($max)

            function getNumber(num) {
                var intNum = parseInt(num);
                return !isNaN(intNum) ? intNum : 0;
            }

            function getMin() {
                var number = getNumber($min.find('option:selected').val());
                console.log(number);
                return number;
            }

            function getMax() {
                var number = getNumber($max.find('option:selected').val());
                console.log(number);
                return number;
            }

            function validateRequiredBoth() {
                if (getMin() == "" && getMax() == "") {
                    return true;
                } else if (getMin() != "" && getMax() == "") {
                    return true;
                } else if (getMin() == "" && getMax() != "") {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            $('#searchForm').validate({
                debug: true,
                onkeyup: false,
                onfocusout: false,
                onclick: false,
                rules: {
                    minrange: {
                        required: function () {
                            return validateRequiredBoth();
                        },
                        max: {
                            param: function () {
                                return getMax();
                            },
                            depends: function () {
                                return getMax() > 0 && getMin() > getMax();
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    maxrange: {
                        required: function () {
                            return validateRequiredBoth();
                        },
                        min: {
                            param: function () {
                                return getMin();
                            },
                            depends: function () {
                                return getMin() > getMax();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                submitHandler: function (formName, event) {
                    console.log('search success');                    
                }
            });

            $("#searchForm").submit(function (e) {
                search();
                return false;
            });


            
        });

        function priceRange() {
            $("#sliderRange").slider({
                range: true,
                min: 0,
                max: 50000,
                values: [0, 50000],
                slide: function (event, ui) {
                    $("#rangePrice").val("$" + ui.values[0] + " - " + "$" + ui.values[1]);
                    $("#minPrice").val(ui.values[0])
                    $("#maxPrice").val(ui.values[1])
                }
            });

            $("#rangePrice").val("$" + $("#sliderRange").slider("values", 0) + " - " +
                "$" + $("#sliderRange").slider("values", 1));
            $("#minPrice").val($("#sliderRange").slider("values", 0));
            $("#maxPrice").val($("#sliderRange").slider("values", 1));
        };

        function minYear() {
            var html = '';
            for (var i = 1980; i <= new Date().getFullYear(); i++) {
                html += '<option value="' + i + '">' + i + '</option>';
            }
            $('#minYear').html(html);
        };

        function maxYear() {
            var html = '';
            for (var i = 1980; i <= new Date().getFullYear(); i++) {
                html += '<option value="' + i + '">' + i + '</option>';
            }
            $('#maxYear').html(html);
        };

        function search() {
            var params;

            params = 'make=' + $('#make').val() + '&model=' + $('#model').val() + '&minYear=' +
                $('#minYear').val() + '&maxYear=' + $('#maxYear').val() + '&minPrice=' + $('#minPrice').val() +
                '&maxPrice=' + $('#maxPrice').val();
            console.log(params)

            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '/api/cars/search?' + params,
                success: function (results) {
                    console.log("success");
                    $('#searchResults').empty();

                    $.each(results, function (index, car) {
                        var html = '<div class="row" style="border: 2px solid #0094ff;">' +
                            '<div class="column one">' +
                            `<h7 class="card-title text-primary"> ${car.Year} ${car.Make.MakeName} ${car.Model.ModelName}</h7><br />` +
                            `<img src="/Images/${car.Photo}" style="height:50px; width:50px;" />` +
                            '</div>' +
                            '<div class="column two">' +
                            '<h7 class="card-title text-primary">' + car.BodyStyle.BodyStyleName + '</h7><br />' +
                            '<h7 class="card-title text-primary">' + car.Transmission.TransmissionType + '</h7><br />' +
                            '<h7 class="card-title text-primary">' + car.ExteriorColor.Color + '</h7>' +
                            '</div>' +
                            '<div class="column three">' +
                            '<h7 class="column card-title text-primary">' + car.InteriorColor.Color + '</h7><br />' +
                            '<h7 class="card-title text-primary">' + car.Mileage + '</h7><br />' +
                            '<h7 class="card-title text-primary">' + car.VIN + '</h7>' +
                            '</div>' +
                            '<div class="column four">' +
                            '<h7 class="column card-title text-primary">' + car.SalePrice + '</h7><br />' +
                            '<h7 class="card-title text-primary">' + car.MSRP + '</h7>' +
                            '<br/>' +
                            '<div class="col-sm-6">' +
                            '<a class="btn btn-primary" href="/Admin/Edit/' + car.CarID + '">Edit</a>' +
                            '</div>' +
                            '</div>' +
                            '</div>'


                        $('#searchResults').append(html.toString());
                    });

                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('Error performing search, try again later!')
                },
                done: function () {
                    alert('Search AJAX complete')
                }
            });


        }
    </script>
}
```

How could I get it to show an error message like in jsfiddle?